# Python 3: Get Bytes from File

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, byte

I'm trying to get bytes from a png file in python 3, and print a string showing the bytes from the png file. However, it gives me this output:

```
b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x00(\x00\x00\x00(\x08\x02\x00\x00\x00\x03\x9c/:\x00\x00\x00\x01sRGB\x00\xae\xce\x1c\xe9\x00\x00\x00\x04gAMA\x00\x00\xb1\x8f\x0b\xfca\x05\x00\x00\x00\tpHYs\x00\x00\x0e\xc3\x00\x00\x0e\xc3\x01\xc7o\xa8d\x00\x00\x01XIDATXG\xe5\xcd\xb1m\x031\x14\x04\xd1\xebF\xad\xb8+\xd5\xe0\x8a\xe5`f\x19|,.\xa0\x0fL\xf4\xc0h\x08.\xafo\xf5>\xc8/a;\xc2/a;\xc2/a;\xc2/a;\xc2/a\x0b\xebC\x1c\r+la}\x88\xa3a\x85-\x88\xbf?\xff=p4\xac\xb0\x05q\xacl\x1c8\x1aV\xd8\x828V6\x0e\x1c\r+lA\x1c+\x1b\x07\x8e\x86\x15\xb6 \x8e\x95\x8d\x03G\xc3\n[\x10\xeb\xca\xbd\xfa\xc4\xd1\xb0\xc2\x16\xc4\xbar\xaf>q4\xac\xb0\x05\xb1\xae|\xde\xafz\xb8\xadO\x1c\r+lA\xac+\xe3\xbfu\xb8\xadO\x1c\r+lA\xac+\xe3\xbfu\xb8\xadO\x1c\r+lA\xac+\xe3\xbfu\xb8\xadO\x1c\r+lA\xac+\xe3\xbfu\xb8\xadO\x1c\r+lA\xac+\xe3\xbfu\xb8\xadO\x1c\r+lA\xac+\xe3\xbfu\xb8\xadO\x1c\r+lA\xac+\xe3\xbfu\xb8\xadO\x1c\r+lA\xac+\xf7\xea\x13G\xc3\n[\x10\xeb\xca\xbd\xfa\xc4\xd1\xb0\xc2\x16\xc4\xb1\xb2q\xe0hXa\x0b\xe2X\xd98p4\xac\xb0\x05q\xacl\x1c8\x1aV\xd8\x828V6\x0e\x1c\r+lA\x1c+\x1b\x07\x8e\x86\x15\xb6\xb0>\xc4\xd1\xb0\xc2\x16\xd6\x878\x1aV\xd8\x8e\xf0K\xd8\x8e\xf0K\xd8\x8e\xf0K\xd8\x8e\xf0K\xd8\x8e\xf0\xcb/s]\x7f\xf8o$|7\xc4\xdf\xeb\x00\x00\x00\x00IEND\xaeB`\x82'
```

instead of normal bytes (here are the bytes it should show): `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`

Here is the code that I wrote to do this:

```
fileread = input("Input File: ")

with open(fileread, 'rb') as readfile:
    string = str(readfile.read())
    readfile.close()
print("String: "+string)
newstr = str(bytes(string, 'utf-8').decode('utf-8'))
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Image data is not utf-8 encoded text.  Do not decode it as if it were.

Answer (score 2):

You've got it right. It's just showing the ASCII representation of the data as that's usually the more useful form

```
>>> s = b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x00(\x00\x00\x00(\x08\x02\x00\x00\x00\x03\x9c/:\x00\x00\x00\x01sRGB\x00\xae\xce\x1c\xe9\x00\x00\x00\x04gAMA\x00\x00\xb1\x8f\x0b\xfca\x05\x00\x00\x00\tpHYs\x00\x00\x0e\xc3\x00\x00\x0e\xc3\x01\xc7o\xa8d\x00\x00\x01XIDATXG\xe5\xcd\xb1m\x031\x14\x04\xd1\xebF\xad\xb8+\xd5\xe0\x8a\xe5`f\x19|,.\xa0\x0fL\xf4\xc0h\x08.\xafo\xf5>\xc8/a;\xc2/a;\xc2/a;\xc2/a;\xc2/a\x0b\xebC\x1c\r+la}\x88\xa3a\x85-\x88\xbf?\xff=p4\xac\xb0\x05q\xacl\x1c8\x1aV\xd8\x828V6\x0e\x1c\r+lA\x1c+\x1b\x07\x8e\x86\x15\xb6 \x8e\x95\x8d\x03G\xc3\n[\x10\xeb\xca\xbd\xfa\xc4\xd1\xb0\xc2\x16\xc4\xbar\xaf>q4\xac\xb0\x05\xb1\xae|\xde\xafz\xb8\xadO\x1c\r+lA\xac+\xe3\xbfu\xb8\xadO\x1c\r+lA\xac+\xe3\xbfu\xb8\xadO\x1c\r+lA\xac+\xe3\xbfu\xb8\xadO\x1c\r+lA\xac+\xe3\xbfu\xb8\xadO\x1c\r+lA\xac+\xe3\xbfu\xb8\xadO\x1c\r+lA\xac+\xe3\xbfu\xb8\xadO\x1c\r+lA\xac+\xe3\xbfu\xb8\xadO\x1c\r+lA\xac+\xf7\xea\x13G\xc3\n[\x10\xeb\xca\xbd\xfa\xc4\xd1\xb0\xc2\x16\xc4\xb1\xb2q\xe0hXa\x0b\xe2X\xd98p4\xac\xb0\x05q\xacl\x1c8\x1aV\xd8\x828V6\x0e\x1c\r+lA\x1c+\x1b\x07\x8e\x86\x15\xb6\xb0>\xc4\xd1\xb0\xc2\x16\xd6\x878\x1aV\xd8\x8e\xf0K\xd8\x8e\xf0K\xd8\x8e\xf0K\xd8\x8e\xf0K\xd8\x8e\xf0\xcb/s]\x7f\xf8o$|7\xc4\xdf\xeb\x00\x00\x00\x00IEND\xaeB`\x82'
>>> s[0]
137
>>> s[1]
80
>>> s[2]
78
>>> hex(s[0])
'0x89'
>>> hex(s[1])
'0x50'
>>> hex(s[2])
'0x4e'
>>>
```

I don't think you'd need the UTF-8 decode step as this is just binary data right?

If you actually want an ASCII representation of the data in hex form to match what you have in the question you could use

```
>>> ''.join('%02x' % c for c in s)
'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'
```

Answer (score 2):

You're getting the bytes fine; you just want to print them differently from the default Python method (which uses characters for printable ASCII codes so you can read them more easily). Just iterate over the bytes and format them however you like:

```
for byte in string:
    print(("%02x" % byte).upper(), end="")
```

If the file isn't too large, you could also do it with one `print()` call by doing the formatting all at once and printing that:

```
print("".join(("%02x" % byte).upper() for byte in string))
```

This will build a string using approximately 6 times the amount of memory as your file before printing it. Use the first method if this could be a problem.

Actually, I just remembered... Python has a module for this!

```
from binascii import hexlify
print(hexlify(string).upper())
```

This will actually use even more memory, since it converts the letters in the hex string to uppercase after building it, but if you're OK with lowercase letters in your hex, this is probably the best solution.

BTW, it's advisable not to call what you read from your file `string`; it's binary data, not text.

Comment: when I do that, it says: `TypeError: %x format: an integer is required, not str`

Comment: It says that if you have a string, but according to the example value in your question, you don't have a string, you have bytes. Iterating over bytes yields integers. Are you sure you're opening the file in binary mode? And you are using Python 3+, right?

Comment: Or are you trying to print the string after UTF-8 decoding? Don't do that.